# Is こればよかった correct or not?

Tags: conjugations

The [Tanos JLPT list](http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/skills/grammar/sentences/?grammarid=516) contains this sentence:

> ディズニーランドはとても面白かったよ。君もこればよかったのに。 Disneyland was very interesting. You should have come with us.

But [the accepted answer at Chiebukuro for 『よかったら、一緒に来れば？』と誰かを誘ったりするときの「来れば？」ですが、...](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1327605988) says:

> 東北辺りでは これば？と言う人もいます
>   方言の一種ですね
>   読み仮名を付ける場合は「くれば」しかありません

Also, my IMEs refuse to convert これば into 来れば, and Rikaichan does not give any meaningful translation for これば.

Is there a contradiction, or am I misunderstanding something?

Is 来ればよかった correct?
Is こればよかった correct?

If there are several definitions of "correct", I am interested in what JLPT deems "correct".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the correct form in standard Japanese is [来]{く}ればよかったのに, since [Wiki](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) says 仮定形 of 来る is くれ.

I think こればよかったのに is a typo or an error. Maybe the person who wrote this uses a regional dialect and typed これば (unconsciously or carelessly?), and it was not converted into kanji so they just left it as it was.

Answer (score 4):

The answer up there you posted seems to make it seem pretty clear to me.

```
東北辺りでは これば？と言う人もいます
方言の一種ですね
読み仮名を付ける場合は「くれば」しかありません
```

is translated to:

```
Around Touhoku, there are some people who say 「これば」.
It's just one type of local dialect. 
But when you write it down, the only correct way is 「くれば」。
```

So in other words, if you are in 東北 and say 「これば」you will be understood just like you can replace 「だ」 with 「や」 in 関西 , but for the JLPT or whenever you're writing formal Japanese, it has to be the Tokyo dialect 「くれば」.

Comment: The Tanos JLPT list seems serious and contains これば so I was wondering which one is correct. Chiebukuro is not always reliable, especially when there is only one answer.

Comment: 「くれば」is the correct form. There's no argument about that. It's just that 「これば」can also mean 「くれば」in slang so that's probably how that incorrect example sentence snuck in there. In english, I'd think of it like "isn't" versus "aint." Yeah, you hear it and understand it, but when it comes down to grammar books, "aint" aint correct. And neither is 「これば」

Comment: "「これば」can also mean 「くれば」in slang". Where do you have that from? Slang used where? I've never heard これば before.

Comment: @dainichi From the Chiebukuro question linked in the OP. One of the answers there links to a paper which contains a survey of the usage of これば vs くらば near the end. From the paper, it seems like これば is quite common among youngsters in Toyama prefecture.

Comment: There is a difference between 「これば」 and 「くれば」. In the example in the OP, 「くれば」 would be "if you had come", whereas 「これば」 would be "if you could have come".

Answer (score 0):

Classic ら抜き + れ抜き (In other words it's a mistake!)

```
これる ==　こられる

これば == こられれば
```

However, 「これる」is in the 大辞林 as meaning "being able to come". Though it does make the note that the "original" (read correct) form is 「こられる」.

http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B

To sum up, ら抜き言葉 is awesome. But れ抜き言葉 is not. I mean which would you rather say, "koreba" or "korarereba"? I don't have time for that. No, wait... Yes I do! Maybe I'll just go with 「これれば」。

Comment: It has nothing to do with ら抜き -- none.  ら抜き is これれば, not これば.

Comment: Sure it does! That is, if you consider 「これる」 to be conjugated as a 五段動詞. Which is where this word comes from according to the dictionary entry I posted. However, if you conjugate it as an 一段動詞 you're absolutely right though, it would be 「これれば」.   I've heard people say both, and I'm pretty sure that both are "incorrect" by 標準語 standards.

Comment: 「これる」は「こられる」のら抜きですよね。助動詞「れる」がついているので、活用形は助動詞の「(ら)れる」の活用になるはずですよね。「(ら)れ、(ら)れ、(ら)れる、(ら)れる、(ら)れれ、(ら)れろ・れよ」って[Wiki](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E_(%E5%9B%BD%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95))に書いてありますので、「れれ」でしょう。仮定形は「れ」ではありません。「れ抜き」になってしまいませんか？読み間違えていたらすみませんが、「『これる』が五段活用する」とおっしゃっているのですか？

Comment: @Maikeru in the 大辞林 entry you linked, it says just below the headword that これる is （ 動ラ下一 ） i.e. 一段. And even if it were the case that it's 五段, the conjugated eba form would still be これれば.

Comment: @Choko 確かに、「これる」とは辞書では一段動詞となっていますね。そう考えますと、「れ抜き」になってしまうことは納得にゆきますよ。但し私は、大辞林では「五段動詞「書く」「読む」の可能動詞「書ける」「読める」などからの類推でできた語」とありますので、こう連想しました：じゃ、{「きる」の未然形が「こ」} and {これる == こられる} （「これる」は「きることができる」の意を表すなら、標準語には存在しない「こる」という類推の五段動詞に基づいているだろうと思って） それで、「これる」はこうして五段動詞活用から派生したものなのであれば、それを第一段階の{こる == きる}という時点で五段活用の仮定形にしたら．．．（こる　⇒　これ） + 「ば」 ⇒　『これば』。筋道なんとなく通っているやろう。:)　どう思われますでしょうか？

Comment: 単に「(か)く>>(か)ける」「(よ)む>>(よ)める」になるから、語尾は「く>>ける」「む>>める」になっているので、「る>>れる」になるだろうと勘違い(類推)して、「(く)る>>(こ)れる」というように間違えたものだと思います。

Comment: (「きる」ってなんのことかよくわかりません。)

Comment: 失礼、{「きる」の未然形が「こ」} ではなく、{「くる」の未然形が「こ」}。

Comment: @Choko: Chokoさんの理論だと「(く)る>>(く)れる」になるはずですよね？
それはともかく、東北の一部では「い」音と「う」音がともに仏語の[y]のような音に同化しているのをご存じですか？ここで、[kyreba]という音の並びは発音しにくいと思いませんか？私は音便的な動機による母音交替だと思います。

Comment: @user4092 「くる>>これる」と言い始めたのがそもそも「類推」による勘違い、「誤り」ですので、こう間違えた人は『いやいや、論理的には「くる>>くれる」になるはずだ』とか論理的なとこまで考えてなかっ‌​たと思いますが・・・。大辞林のいう「五段動詞「書く」「‌​読む」の可能動詞「書ける」「読める」などからの類推でできた語」とは、他のいくつかの動詞が「辞書形>>可能形」が」「～く>>～ける」とか「～む>>～める」だから、「来る」も、「～る>>～られる」ではなく「～る>>～れる」のように思えたことによる勘違い、という意味ではないのですか？[y]の読み方はわかりません。きれば、みたいな感じですか？「きれば」が「これば」になった、とおっしゃってるんですか？

Comment: それだと「類推による間違い」というより「類推の間違い」という気がしますがまぁどっちみち間違いなのでそれは置いといて。
[y]音云々に関しては、「くれば」がうまく発音できないので「これば」で近似した、ということです。

Comment: Choko is totally right about the way this word was born based on mistakenly applied 五段 conjugation principles. I was taking things too far by imagining a word like 「こる」。頭が凝ってきたなぁ．．．！